# How to fix dbcontext scaffold "Login failded for user {'username}"

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

When I am trying to connect to my Azure SQL Database via Enitity Framework Core I always get the Error Message "Login failed for User {'Username'}", how can I fix this?

I tried with this Code:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=tcp:XXX.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Calculator;Persist Security Info=True;User ID={XXX};Password={XXX};MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

The Username and password are the credentials from the DB Owner, so I should have all the rights I need.

And I recieve this Error Message:

```
Login failed for User {XXX}
```

At first I updated my Firewall rules and added my IP Adress.

I have already tried to connect the project with a local DB, which worked fine.

Furthermore I logged into the DB via SSMS which worked fine too.

Did I forget to modify some Settings?

For my Defense: Its the first time I am using Azure so please be kind if its a dumb error.

Comment: I would check the password of the user {xxx}, does it contain some special characters?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have already changed the password and tried another one but it did not work too.

Comment: Can you try removing the `Persist Security Info=True;` part/option from your connection string?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i tried but same result

Comment: Double check your connection string, dbname, user id and pw. 
The least probable cause, due to the error message - is the firewall. Try turning it off for a minute on your own machine, and add a rule on Azure, using the IP range of 0.0.0.0 and 255.255.255.255, which will open it up to all IPs. If this doesn't fix it, you at least know is has to be something regarding the db and user permissions.

Comment: If it's not the firewall, and because you're firing this connection string within a Cli, first try setting a password that doesn't contain any special characters. Other than that, recheck your permissions - even if you can login via Ssms.  Azure DB gives a user access to only a certain db, so check what roles and what permissions that user has assigned and try to grant it any connect, read, write role/perm etc. specifically within the db.

Comment: ok so the hint with the firewall didnt work either, i triple checked the connection string and i tried to turn off the firewall and the stuff with the ip, nothing worked for me

Comment: I am using the DB Owner, so all rights should be given I guess, password is atm without any special chars (did not work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: Azure is delivering the wrong connection string!

As a workaround, I connected my Server via VS and copied the connection string from there.

It worked pretty fine.

The difference is that I put instead of Server, "Data Source" into the connection string:

```
Data Source=xxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=PhoneCalculator;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False
```

And that's it x)